# JTextfield array, retrieve name and text

Tags: java, arrays, swing, actionlistener, jtextfield

I have an array of `JTextField` and when a `JTextField` is modified I want to have the name of the `JTextField` and the text.

```java
while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) { // 1 by 1 line of file
    if (f == 6) {
        g++;
        f = 0;
    }
    tableauDonnee[g][f] = line;
    fields[g][f] = new JTextField(tableauDonnee[g][f]);
    fields[g][f].setName(String.valueOf(g + etf));
    fields[g][f].setBounds(positionY, positionX, 160, 40);
    pan.add(fields[g][f]);
    positionY = positionY + 180;
    f++;
```

I can do that before add `JTextField` to panel

```java
fields[g][f].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        textfield = fields[g][f].getText();
        nameTextfield = fields[g][f].getName();
    }
});
```

But it will not work because values of `g` and `f` are not good.

I'm stuck and don't know what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the source of the event (ie, the text field where you pressed the Enter key) from the `ActionEvent`:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) 
{
    JTextField textField = (JTextField)event.getSource();
    ...
}
```

Also, why are you use a 2D array of text fields.

I would suggest a `JTable` would be the better components to use. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Tables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for more information.

Comment: If i use it it return me that javax.swing.JTextField[5,750,110,160x40,layout=javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI$UpdateHandler,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=javax.swing.plaf.BorderUIResource$CompoundBorderUIResource@4fa1d375,flags=296,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,caretColor=sun.swing.PrintColorUIResource[r=51,g=51,b=51],disabledTextColor=javax.swing.plaf.ColorUIResource[r=184,g=207,b=229],editable=true,margin=javax.swing.plaf.InsetsUIResource[top=0,left=0,bottom=0,right=0],sel etc. Where can i retrieve the name and text. By the way textfield is a string not a jtextfield

Comment: Excuse me your a genius. I take textfield as jtexfield and after i retrieve name and text from textfield